# Best way to deploy PHP website with Gulp

Tags: php, git, gulp, web-deployment, rsync

What is the best way to deploy PHP Website with Bower components and Gulp tasks?

- Is it good to install npm on production server for run Gulp tasks?
- If not, is it good to commit minified files (CSS, JavaScript, compressed images) in Git?
- If not, is it good to use rsync for prepare and (push) deploy project to remote server and then use post deploy script for set up chmods, update database etc?

Maybe there is better way to do that?

Comment: It's not for committing things in Git, no. If you want to do minification, use Gulp as part of your build process that creates minified and uglified versions, and don't commit them. Your Bower and Composer dependencies are not committed, these are the same.

Comment: You can do a build on the server or off it, as you choose - I don't think there's an advantage to one or the other. Rsync is fine as a transport mechanism. Don't make the new build live though until it is ready - you can switch symlinks, or modify the vhost and bounce Apache for that, all as part of the post-deploy script. On the broad topic of deployment, maybe [this will help](https://leftnode.org/posts/expert-php-deployments.html)?

Comment: @halfer thanks for your answer. So far I use rsync and post-script wrote in bash. My post script set up chmods, migrates, cache etc. That was good?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. If it's robust, and bails if there's a problem (e.g. migrations resulted in a SQL error) - the process must not take down your service if there's a problem. Of course, you could just do a test deployment in staging, and only run it in live if staging returns cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, that are really helpful informations. What about phing + jenkins? Jenkins provide test/build tools and can be integrated with phing. But the disadvantage for me are repeated jobs. My jobs are customs. In some days i need deploy project twice or more, other time zero.

Comment: I don't have any Jenkins experience. The link I supplied talks about Phing a great deal. Use these tools if they make it easier to get going, but you may be in danger of overcomplicating your first attempt. Write a script (Phing, PHP, shell, Gulp, whatever) that pushes your code to the remote server, does all the pre-live actions (e.g. minifying), puts the app into maintenance mode, switches the symlink to make it live, runs the migrations, takes the app of maintenance mode, then cleans up.

Comment: (You can probably do the process without a maintenance mode, if you are willing to do database feature detection in your code (e.g. if column X is present, do this, else do that). Also, you can take web servers out of a round-robin cluster, one at a time, and upgrade each in turn. However, that's if you have the traffic and budget to justify such as operation).

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to make sure everything works on your production server is by deploying first to a staging environment. This could be very well the same server, just not accessible for everyone.

As an example: we have a website: www.website.com, which is the live environment.

Assume we have another subdomain called staging.website.com which points to the same server but has its own `DocumentRoot` ([more on DocumentRoot](http://www.karelia.com/support/sandvox/help/z/Document_Root.html)) but it is protected by some form of authentication (or an IP firewall, in our company's case. If it is not authorized to see staging, it will just point to the www.website.com, very convenient).

You would first deploy to the staging, there run all the build scripts (Composer, Gulp, minify), test out if everything still works. If it does, you can just easily point the `DocumentRoot` of the live domain to the staging directory and it's done.

As for committing minified files, no. You should commit the original files and the builder scripts. The minified scripts will all be built every time you deploy your application.

You could use Rsync, but like I suggested you should build your application (chmod, database etc) during deployment. Not afterwards.

Comment: thanks you for your answer. Concluding: should I install npm and bower on production server and use it on staging environment?

Comment: "You should commit the original [JavaScript/CSS] files" - only if they are part of your codebase. If they are libraries, they should be brought in using a package manager and not committed.

Comment: If your staging server is the same as the production server, then yes. Remember that if you have separate servers, the development, staging and production servers should be really close to each other configuration wise.

Thank you for editting my answer and adding the above clarification halfer.